# Count issue when introducing a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fairly new to SQL. I'm trying to count the total number of booking ID's in a query for holidays that are sometimes in two regions.

This is want I need..

```
ID        count  Region name
427139        1  France
427776        2  Spain
427776        2  France
```

But only seem to deliver this..

```
ID        count  Region name
427139        1  France
427776        1  Spain
427776        1  France
```

Bookings ID's are unique but get split into 2 rows when I introduce Region from my Region table (via Quotes and Properties tables.)

Here's my SQL..

```
SELECT count(BO.ID) as Count,
       BO.ID AS 'Booking ID',
       RE.Name AS 'Region name'
FROM Booking BO WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN Quote QU WITH (NOLOCK) ON QU.ID = BO.QuoteID 
  LEFT JOIN Property PR WITH (NOLOCK) ON PR.Code = QU.Code 
  LEFT JOIN Region RE WITH (NOLOCK) ON RE.ID = PR.RegionID 
WHERE BO.ID = '427776' OR BO.ID = '427139'
Group by BO.ID,RE.Name 
ORDER BY BO.ID
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Why are you expecting "2" for those rows?  Do you want to count the total regions per ID on each row?  And which database are you using?

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: Wanted to show the total regions per BO.ID so I can attribute the booking share out.  Below works for me!

Comment: Using NOLOCK everywhere is a habit you do not want to start.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: OK Mark, will look at this.  Was told to use it to start with so will check out your link. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLServer2005+ you can use OVER() clause with aggregate function COUNT()

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY BO.ID) as [Count],
       BO.ID AS 'Booking ID',
       RE.Name AS 'Region name' 
FROM Booking BO WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN Quote QU WITH (NOLOCK) ON QU.ID = BO.QuoteID 
  LEFT JOIN Property PR WITH (NOLOCK) ON PR.Code = QU.Code 
  LEFT JOIN Region RE WITH (NOLOCK) ON RE.ID = PR.RegionID
WHERE BO.ID = '427776' OR BO.ID = '427139'
GROUP BY BO.ID, RE.Name
ORDER BY BO.ID
```

I think the request in the new format can be used without GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY BO.ID) as [Count],
       BO.ID AS 'Booking ID',
       RE.Name AS 'Region name' 
FROM Booking BO WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN Quote QU WITH (NOLOCK) ON QU.ID = BO.QuoteID 
  LEFT JOIN Property PR WITH (NOLOCK) ON PR.Code = QU.Code 
  LEFT JOIN Region RE WITH (NOLOCK) ON RE.ID = PR.RegionID
WHERE BO.ID = '427776' OR BO.ID = '427139'
ORDER BY BO.ID
```

Comment: Great!, both work for me.  Really appreciate your help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading up on aggregate functions in SQL (this was the best link I could find) :

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/group-by.php

GROUP BY gathers your results into groups, and then the aggregate function is called on each group.  Since you are grouping by ID and region, you will get the count for that ID and region - rather than the count just for that ID.

So it's just a matter of choosing which group you want to get the count for.

Comment: (although mysql has some extra different behaviour for GROUP BY, hence Alex asking which DB system you have)

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks will read up..  Not sure what the database is so will find out!

Comment: and I will read up on OVER / PARTITION ;) apparently it is useful in exactly your use case ... when you want aggregate information for some group without actually rolling up the group into a single row